# I can not get in to url of my DSpace

Tags: apache, tomcat, dspace

I've finished installing the DSpace 6.2 after some problems, the problem is that after starting the Tomcat and enter the URL does not show anything

[image: Don't show anything]

Comment: Your post does not contain any information about your setup. Also, Stack Overflow is an English-speaking community, so it may generally be better to post the error message from an English browser version (in this case it clearly refers to a name resolution error).

Answer (score 0):

Have you deployed your xmlui webapp into your servlet container (i.e. Tomcat webapps folder)?

Comment: yes i did it, but i had to deploy xmlui only?, cause i deployed all webapps from dsapce/webapps

Comment: No no its okay if you deployed all of them as long as you specify which you want to launch from your URL, as I see you've done. Lastly, did you specify your webapp in your dspace.cfg? It needs to be explicitly enabled in the file line 32 . check if `dspace.ui = xmlui`